# What is the name of a fantasy TV series that features crystals as an element a lot?

Tags: story-identification, magic, magical-items

I believe it is a classic adventure fantasy. The protagonist is a teenaged boy with a bow and arrow and long hair. There is a girl, of course, and I think there is an evil witch, but I may be wrong on that one. The crystals, I think, are magical or may even be used as energy weapons, and, I'm not sure about this, the crystals may even grow all over the landscape. The series is from the 90's to the early 2000's.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is this animated or live-action?  American?

Comment: Live-action. Most likely American, bu

Comment: ...but could also be Australian or Canadian.

Comment: what country did you watch it in

Comment: I doubt it's gonna be of much help, but i watched it in Serbia. Obviously imported, obviously low budget because at the time local networks didn't have the money to pay for top shows.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be [*Spellbinder*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spellbinder_%28TV_series%29)? Not sure on the long hair, but there are energy crystals and a female antagonist.

Comment: Looked Spellbinder up, that's not it but definitely good try though. 
No connection to the present or real world, all is in the fantasy.
The crystals were blue or blueish to white...

Thanks a lot anyway, Spellbinder look like a good show.